# Excel: Better Percentage Ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am attempting to write up some tables which automatically populate with a percentage range based on if there are any contents, (and how many contents overall).

Picture is what I am looking for, if you enter info in the blank boxes it automatically calculates the new ranges, and vice-versa by deleting any.

[image: Percentage Ranges]
.

I already have a working code, but it feels clunky and I'm worried that if I had a whole datasheet full of this that it will more than likely crash.

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C84)),
(
TEXT(COUNTA(B84:$B84)/COUNTA($B84:$N84)+0.01,"0%")
)&"-"& TEXT(
COUNTA(B84:$B84)/COUNTA($B84:$N84)+1/COUNTA($B84:$N84),"0%"),"-")
```

Any suggestions on trimming this?

Comment: Why the double function in the logical_test portion of your formula? You use NOT(ISBLANK()) instead of ISBLANK(). I'd suggest getting rid of the NOT() and switching the [value_is_true] and [value_is_false] parameters. That would be one less function that has to be called.  


`=IF(ISBLANK(C84),"-",
(
TEXT(COUNTA(B84:$B84)/COUNTA($B84:$N84)+0.01,"0%")
)&"-"& TEXT(
COUNTA(B84:$B84)/COUNTA($B84:$N84)+1/COUNTA($B84:$N84),"0%"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What info are you entering, and into which cells? Is the desired outcome a summary or a line by line result?

Comment: The Info I am entering is the data underneath the percent ranges (or underneath the "-" in the example). So in the picture "Item A, Item 2, Item C" etc

Comment: There is a lot of analysis going on here so there

Comment: You could maybe set up a table off to the side where each value is referenced and the ranking returned but it will still be doing a lot of work and I don't think it will reduce the 'clutter'. I agree with gwhenning to change the double-negative at the start to '=IF(ISBLANK(C$84),"-",(TEXT(COUNTA(B84:$B84)/COUNTA($B84:$N84)+0.01,"0%"))&"-"& TEXT(COUNTA(B84:$B84)/COUNTA($B84:$N84)+1/COUNTA($B84:$N84),"0%"))'. The only real way to do it is through vba. Hope this helps.

Comment: Agh, I wanted to avoid VBA because I need to share this with others that might need to make changes, but I guess it's the best option. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Update: This works slightly better =TEXT((COUNTA($C3:C3)-1)/COUNTA($C3:$I3),"0%")&" - "&TEXT(COUNTA($C3:C3)/COUNTA($C3:$I3),"0%")